# jQuery Mobile - button style - Padding issue

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile

Please see the photo below to understand the problem:

[image]

I have a problem with padding here. I cant place the text of the button "Online Map" in the middle of the button. I'm developing this application for Android.

HTML:

```
<div class="footer" data-tap-toggle="false">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="ui-grid-b">
<div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#page_19_EN" data-rel="back">Back</a></div> 
<div class="ui-block-b"> 
<a data-theme="my-site" data-role="button" data-mini="true" onClick="checkReachability()">Online Map</a>      
</div> 
 <div class="ui-block-c home"><a href="#page_41_EN">Home</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-btn-up-my-site { 
    color: white;       
    font-size:8px;      
    padding-top:0;
    padding-left:0 !important;
    border:1px solid #333;
    text-align:left !important;
    padding-right:0;
    margin-top:-10px ;
    white-space: normal;                 
}

.footer .ui-grid-b .ui-block-a, .footer .ui-grid-b .ui-block-c { width: 20%; } 
.footer .ui-grid-b .ui-block-b { width: 60%; text-align: center; padding:0;}
```

I spent over 5 hours trying to style this button and still didn't succeed. It driving me nuts..
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this issue happening in android only?

Comment: Actually I don't know... I can only test in on Android..

Comment: I meant in desktop browsers,is this issue reproducable?.If so please post sample code jsfiddle where the issue can be reproduced

Comment: NO, in the issue doesn't appear in desktop browser. Maybe because, as far as I understand, desktop browser dont parse elements such are: data-theme="my-site" data-role="button" data-mini="true"....etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting

```
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
```

Sometime it solved apparently padding problems for me. Hope it'll work.

Comment: Tried, didnt solve the issue. But still cause some changes.. See image again.

Comment: Have you tried putting a negative value to margin-left and remove margin-right or the other way around? Sorry for the question, just to be sure

Comment: No, nothing.. It doesn't affect at all. I even put !important behind those attributes...

Comment: Sorry I just noticed 2 things:

1ts: try removing text-align: center;

2nd: why you don't try using jquery mobile navbar instead of creating your own divs and override just the sizes?

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html